# Neo4j ResultSet Object - how to get data if result is an array

Tags: neo4j, resultset, gremlin

I have one gremlin query in which I used `cap().next()`

and `Everyman\Neo4j\Query\ResultSet` `Object` is

...

```
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [v[1079]] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14
            )

        [v[1082]] => Array
            (
                [0] => 25
            )

        [v[1016]] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
            )

        [v[1078]] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
            )

        [v[1081]] => Array
            (
                [0] => 17
            )

    )
```

...

how to get that array?

`$result[0][0]` is not working.

Comment: I forgot to say that I using this in PHP

Answer (score 1):

To iterate ResultSets use

```
 foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['x']->getProperty('your_property') . "\n";
}
```

or with scalar values in column y

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo $row['x']->getProperty('your_property') . ": " . $row['y'] ."\n";
```

}

It would be nice to have the original gremlin query thought to see what you are returning from it.

see [github](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Cypher-and-gremlin-queries)